# Get values of variables defined by protocol from any VC

Tags: ios, swift2, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

protocol(myProtocol):-

```
 protocol myProtocol {
        var type:String { get set }
        var sub:String { get }
        var msg:String? { get set }
    }
```

Class(myVC):-

```
class myVC: UIViewController, myProtocol {
    //Protocol Declarations
    var sub  = myTypes.type.rawValue
    var type = myTypes.type.getType()
    var msg :String?

.... }
```

Extension:-

```
extension UIViewController
{
 func getData() {
        if self is myProtocol {
         let msg = self.msg

        } }
}
```

Getting error at 'self.msg' saying `Value of type UIViewController has no member 'sub'`

How do i go about it?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is write another line of code in your extension class. I just tested it in my end and it worked for me. Here is the code I wrote -

```html
extension UIViewController
{
    func getData() {
        if self is myProtocol {
            let x = self as! myProtocol
            let msg = x.msg
            print(x.msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @AKMSalehSultan

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you need to change your extension definition

```
extension UIViewController
```

as

```
extension myVC
```